# Motivation and intuition behind the geometric product integral

Tags: integration, analysis, intuition, products

According to the relevant [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral), there are three types of product integrals. Type II, the *geometric integral*, is named as the continuous analogue of the discrete product operator.

The geometric integral is defined as follows:

$$\prod_{a}^{b} f(x)^{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x_{i})^{\Delta x} = \exp \left( \int_{a}^{b} \ln f(x) \ dx \right). $$

I am looking for some intuition and a motivation behind this definition. It is not clear to me exactly how the equality on the right hand is arrived at, and why it represents a continuous analogue of the discrete product operator.

How can this definition be motivated? And what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: Intuition behind $$\prod_{a}^{b} f(x)^{\Delta x} \approx \exp \left( \int_{a}^{b} \ln f(x) \ dx \right) \ \ ? $$ (you have seen that I have modified a little your equality). Taking the $\ln$ on each side, you will plainly have a Riemann sum of $\ln(f(...))$ on the LHS corresponding to the integral of $\ln(f(...))$ on $(a,b)$ on the RHS.

Comment: This is also motivated by viewing an integral as a weighted average: $$ \frac{1}{b-1}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \simeq \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)\frac{x_i-x_{i-1}}{b-a} = \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)p_i, $$ where $$\sum_{i=1}^N p_i = 1. $$ The geometric average analogue would therefore be $$ \prod_{i=1}^N (f(x_i))^{p_i} = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^N (\log f(x_i))p_i\right) \simeq \exp\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \log f(x)\,dx\right). $$